# How to bypass certificate checking in a Java web service client

Tags: java, https, wsdl

Use Case:
There is a web service posted as https://a.b.c.d/zz?wsdl

What i would like to do is to query this URI and IF i get a VALID WSDL, i return a boolean "true" else "false.
Now, if i go via Chrome browser to this URL, i would have to manually do an accept on the cert warning, and THEN the WSDL gets downloaded. But how can do this via Java / HttpsURLConnection

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.io.*;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class JavaHttpsExample
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  throws Exception
  {
    String httpsURL = "https://a.b.c.d/zz/V2.0/api?wsdl";
    URL myurl = new URL(httpsURL);
    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)myurl.openConnection();
    InputStream ins = con.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(ins);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);

    String inputLine;

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
    {
      System.out.println(inputLine);
    }

    in.close();
  }
}
```

and i get an error:

> Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names
>   matching IP address a.b.c.d found     at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
>     at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
>     at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
>     at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
>     at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown
>   Source)   at JavaHttpsExample.main(JavaHttpsExample.java:14) Caused by:
>   java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names
>   matching IP address a.b.c.d found     at
>   sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchIP(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown
>   Source)

i have replaced the real IP with a.b.c.d (of course)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Don't use a stubbed out TrustManager as this makes your application trust ***everyone***. I would recommend downloading the certificate presented by the site and adding it to a private, trusted keystore. This lets you make an exception for that one site without greenlighting everyone.

I also like this approach because it requires no code changes.

In Chrome, click the lock icon to the left of the url. Then click "Certificate Information". Go to the "Details" tab and click "Copy to file". Save it as a "base64 encoded X.509 (.cer)" to "SITENAME.cer".

Copy $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts to your application's directory as "mykeystore.jks".

Install the certificate with:

```
keytool -keystore mykeystore.jks -storepass changeit -importcert -alias SITENAME -trustcacerts -file SITE.cer
```

Now, when you run your application, tell it to use the private certificate store:

```
java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=mykeystore.jks ...
```

Comment: that's the difference between experience and amateur :) nice answer

Comment: In Chrome 47 it is not possible to save the certificate anymore, as far as I can see. This step can be done with Firefox, however.

Comment: @simon It works for me on Chrome 47 and 48. Now if you're on a Mac instead of "Copy to File" you have to drag the certificate icon to your desktop or a Finder window and that will create the .cer file.

Answer (score 7):

Just Implement your own trust manager like in the below code

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.io.*;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

public class JavaHttpsExample
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  throws Exception
  {
    String httpsURL = "https://a.b.c.d/zz?wsdl";
    URL myurl = new URL(httpsURL);
    SSLContext ssl = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1");
    ssl.init(null, new TrustManager[]{new SimpleX509TrustManager()}, null);
    SSLSocketFactory factory = ssl.getSocketFactory();


    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)myurl.openConnection();
    con.setSSLSocketFactory(factory);
    InputStream ins = con.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(ins);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);

    String inputLine;

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
    {
      System.out.println(inputLine);
    }

    in.close();
  }
}

class SimpleX509TrustManager implements X509TrustManager {
    public void checkClientTrusted(
            X509Certificate[] cert, String s)
            throws CertificateException {
    }

    public void checkServerTrusted(
            X509Certificate[] cert, String s)
            throws CertificateException {
      }

    @Override
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: In your source code above, where does "SimpleX509TrustManager" come from?