# Scala dispatch: Set default hostname verifier?

Tags: scala, ssl

For my development machine, I'd like to disable SSL hostname checks for HTTPS connections. The exception that comes out of the dispatch code is this:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match: <localhost> != <*.mydomain.com> OR <*.mydomain.com> OR <mydomain.com>
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:228) ~[httpclient-4.1.3.jar:4.1.3]
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.BrowserCompatHostnameVerifier.verify(BrowserCompatHostnameVerifier.java:54) ~[httpclient-4.1.3.jar:4.1.3]
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:149) ~[httpclient-4.1.3.jar:4.1.3]
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:130) ~[httpclient-4.1.3.jar:4.1.3]
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:397) ~[httpclient-4.1.3.jar:4.1.3]
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:148) ~[httpclient-4.1.3.jar:4.1.3]
```

I'm looking for a way to set the default hostname verifier in a way that will be used by dispatch. There's [a method on the deprecated HttpsURLConnection](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html#setDefaultHostnameVerifier%28javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier%29) to set the default hostname verifier, but that whole class is apparently deprecated. Is there a current correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It's [com.sun.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/com/sun/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html) that was deprecated in favor of [javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html); the latter isn't deprecated.

As to the ways to bypass this check, you could:

- Modify the certificate store (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11991284/how-to-bypass-certificate-checking-in-a-java-web-service-client) question)
- Use a JVM option (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663147/is-there-a-java-setting-for-disabling-certificate-validation) question)