# Spring boot server + java Client

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ssl, https

I want to create HTTPS connection between my Spring-boot server and my JavaFx client. Can you help me about that?

Here is my example: (This is my Controller class)

```
@RestController
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "Hello World " + new Date();
    }
}
```

I create a key like this ->

```
keytool.exe" -genkey -alias springboot -storetype PKCS12 -keyalg RSA -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore mykeystore.12 -validity 3650
```

after I set in application.properties like this:

```
server.port=8443
server.ssl.key-store=mykeystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=changeit
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-alias=springboot
```

now the server works. But I cannot send HTTPS request from my java client.

```
package com.company;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;

public class Main {

    private static final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            sendGet();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void sendGet() throws Exception {

        String url = "https://localhost:8443/";

        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        // optional default is GET
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");

        //add request header
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        //print result
        System.out.println(response.toString());

    }

}

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1964)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:328)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:322)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1614)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1052)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:987)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1072)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1564)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:347)
    at com.company.Main.sendGet(Main.java:33)
    at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:14)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:397)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:302)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1596)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:392)
    ... 21 more
`
```

I tried this solution: ["PKIX path building failed" and "unable to find valid certification path to requested target"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076179/pkix-path-building-failed-and-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requ) but it can't work.

Comment: "but it can't work" => Why? This is exactly what you have to do ...

Answer (score 0):

Your client doesn't trust your server's self-signed certificate. For testing purposes you will need to either:

1. Import the certificate as a trusted CA into a JKS truststore and configure your client to use it. The `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` property is the easiest way to do that.
2. Disable all SSL trust checking on the client.

Both approaches are [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11991284/how-to-bypass-certificate-checking-in-a-java-web-service-client). Please heed the warnings when disabling trust checking.